# How to check if dictionary keys match dictionary values in order

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if each key/value pair of a dictionary match, with the resulting output being `True` or `False`.

I thought the below code would return `True` because the keys/values are the same, but `False` is returned.

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\path\\to\\directory'
saved_names = os.listdir(path)

cell_names = []

for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", on_bad_lines='skip', header=None)
    myMatrix = df[df.columns[0]].to_numpy()
    cell_names.extend(myMatrix.tolist())

cell_names_csv = list(map(lambda x: x +'.csv', cell_names))
joined_lists = dict(zip(saved_names, cell_names_csv))
print(joined_lists.keys())
print(joined_lists.values())

if joined_lists.keys() == joined_lists.values():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['weekly report 12457.csv', monthly report 14796.csv', yearly report79652.csv'])
dict_values(['weekly report 12457.csv', monthly report 14796.csv', yearly report79652.csv'])
False
```

The reason for the `False` output must be due to the `dict_keys` and `dict_values` being held in the variable. Is there a way to remove this? Or an alternative way?

Comment: "keys()" and "values()" return views of the dictionary. Convert them to tuples or lists first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `if list(joined_lists.keys()) == list(joined_lists.values()):`

An example demonstration:

```
>>> my_dict = {"a":"a","b":"b"}
>>> my_dict.keys() == my_dict.values()
False
>>> list(my_dict.keys()) == list(my_dict.values())
True
```

Comment: Great, that resolved it. Thanks a lot.

If they dont match, is there a simple way to print the unmatching key in the else block?

Comment: `[key for i, key in enumerate(list(my_dict.keys())) if key != list(my_dict.values())[i]]` contains the unmatching keys. If `list(my_dict.keys()) == list(my_dict.values())` is `True`, then this list should be empty